# Golang Parametric Functions

Tags: go, parameter-passing, variadic-functions, optional-parameters

I am trying to use Go parametric functions as its described in the following link 
[Functional options for friendly APIs](https://dave.cheney.net/2014/10/17/functional-options-for-friendly-apis) - however I am getting a type error which I am not sure why.

I am adding my code here for your review:

[Sample Code Here](https://play.golang.org/p/xJX_mrGJO8a)

The error message is:

> prog.go:35:18: cannot use port (type func(*Server)) as type func(*Server) error in argument to NewServer

Comment: I'm not sure what a "parametric function" is, but your signatures don't match -- `"func(*Server)" != "func(*Server) error"`

Comment: Thanks JimB. I have functions with optional parameters - I found the article on web and it was a good approach. I have added the link to my post.

Answer (score 0):

As JimB pointed out, the signatures need to match entirely, including the return value. In your sample code, either have port return error, e.g.:

```
port := func(srv *Server) error {
    srv.Port = 8080
    return nil
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LYb846jBD-m

Or remove error from the definition of NewServer:

```
func NewServer(name string, options ...func(srv *Server)) *Server
```

https://play.golang.org/p/4PGN3TRkBpq